# Rails, Carrierwave image rotation. After image rotation It shows an old version of image that already doesn't exist.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, carrierwave, image-rotation

I do a rails project and I'm using carrierwave gem and jCrop jQuery plugin to avatar processing  and I use image rotation. I've implemented it by ajax and after  rotation and saving of new  image position I do render json with image-path. Then using ajax:success I put this image to opened croper-form, to continue avatar processing. I see that after every request an image has rotated but image-path continues to reference to the old version of image that was before rotation. As a result I be able to show user just first rotation result  (90 degrees) because other rotation regardless it works for images user can't see because image path continues to reference to the old version of image.

avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def serializable_hash
    model.read_attribute :url
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  version :large do
    process :rotate!#by default 0 degrees
    process :resize_to_limit => [500, 500]
  end

  version :rotation, from_version: :large do
  end

  def rotate!
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.rotate!(model.rotation_value)
    end
  end
```

avatar.rb

```
class User::Avatar < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user

  def rotate_avatar!
    #rotation angle I keep in a database
    update(rotation_value: rotation_value + 90)
    image.recreate_versions!
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def rotate_avatar
    avatar = @user.avatars.last
    avatar.rotate_avatar!
    render json: {avatar: avatar.image_url(:rotation)}
  end
```

avatar.js.coffee

```
$(document).on 'click', '.rotate-avatar-button', (e) ->
  $("form.rotate-avatar").bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    avatar_path = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)['avatar']
    $('#avatar-modal-box').html(JST["templates/cropper"]({img_path: avatar_path}))
```

I guess the reason is that carriervawe caches image.
I have tried to find out how to disable caching, but found only that it's  impossible https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/955, 
and way that not working for me https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/0lH40VP1zI4

For me it is important that after  image rotation it was saved on the server, because after rotation - the image should be asynchronously loaded into jCrop form and user can crop the avatar as it needs

How can I disable caching or may be there is another way to solve it?.
Thanks in advance for any advice.